# Set filename for PDFKit piped to HTTP response

Tags: node.js, express, node-pdfkit

How can I set the filename for a PDF file created with pdfKit for sending via HTTP (rather than saving locally).  The following doesn't set the filename and the decs only show how to set the file name for saving locally.

```
var doc = new PDFDocument({bufferPages: true});
doc.info.Title = 'Case ' + req.params.id + ' overview';
// Some more content here
doc.pipe(res);
```

I've tried setting headers too but that doesn't seem to help.

```
res.setHeader('Content-disposition', 'attachment; filename=testFile.pdf');
```

Comment: `Content-disposition` header should help. Make sure to call `doc.end()` to finalize the stream. Does file download at all?

Comment: The file downloads fine but get's named download.pdf, I'm assuming by the browser

Comment: Did you figure this out?

Answer (score 6):

I know this is a old thread but this answer may be helpful to some one I think.

```
let doc = new PDFDocument();
doc.info['Title'] = 'Test Document';
```

Answer (score 2):

Even though this is old, I am commenting because it took me a while to find the working solution and this is still the top google response.

To get the PDF to display in the browser but define the download name I used:

```
res.setHeader('Content-disposition', 'inline; filename='+ yourfilename +'.pdf');
```

hope this helps someone else.

Comment: This doesn't work if you set the disposition to `inline`. The filename only works for disposition `attachment`